# Как установить значение свойства равное имени поля класса?

Tags: c#, ооп, атрибуты

Как сделать так, чтобы в MembershipFunctionParam.Name хранилось название под которым оно храниться как поле для класса TriangleFunction. То есть чтобы в TriangleFunction a.Name = "a", b.Name = "b", c.Name = "c"? 
Без исопльзования коструктора для решения вопроса.
Полагаю тут задействуются атрибуты...

```
//параметр для ф-и принадлежности
public class MembershipFunctionParam
{
    public string Name{get; set;}        //имя
    public double Value { get; set; }    //значение

    //преобразование в строку - для отладки
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name+"="+Value;
    }

    //преобразование для удобного использования
    public static implicit operator double(MembershipFunctionParam p)
    {
        return p.Value;
    }
}

//абстрактная ф-я принадлежности
public abstract class MembershipFunction
{
    //список параметов 
    //из количество отличается от ф-и (в сигмоидальной - 2, треугольной - 3 и т. д.)
    public List<MembershipFunctionParam> Params;

    //ф-я принадлежности
    public abstract double GetValue(double x);
}

//треугольная ф-я принадлежности
public class TriangleFunction:MembershipFunction
{
    //параметры функции
    MembershipFunctionParam a = new MembershipFunctionParam();
    MembershipFunctionParam b = new MembershipFunctionParam();
    MembershipFunctionParam c = new MembershipFunctionParam();

    //приватный конструктор, который добавляет в параметрны этой ф-и в список параметров родительского класса
    private TriangleFunction()
    {
        Params.Add(a);
        Params.Add(b);
        Params.Add(c);
    }

    //конструктор, который принимает значения параметов
    public TriangleFunction(double a, double b,double c)
        :this()
    {
        this.a.Value = a;
        this.b.Value = b;
        this.c.Value = c;
    }

    //подсчет ф-и принадлежности
    public override double GetValue(double x)
    {
        if (x >= a && x < b)
            return (x - a) / (b - a);

        else if (x >= b && x <= c)
            return (c - x) / (c - b);

        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: например передавать этот параметр в конструктор

Comment: @Grundy Уточнил вопрос. Без использования конструктора для этой цели.

Comment: а ты понимаешь, что сейчас у тебя `a`, `b`,`c` - это `null`?

Comment: Да. Я потом в конструкторе их приму.

Comment: если ты их принимаешь извне - то ты никак не можешь знать что именно тебе придет

Comment: А когда этот `MembershipFunctionParam a` будет передан в другой метод в параметр с именем `Uberwonderparameter` - что должен будет возвращать `Name`?

Comment: Можете использовать template и спросить у T его имя.

Comment: Типа так `void Add<T>(T item){   string name= typeof(T).Name; object value = item;  }`

Comment: @nick_n_a, и что это даст `typeof(T).Name`?

Comment: @nick_n_a а толку-то? Не имя типа нужно. нужно имя экземпляра, причём если я правильно именно то имя, которое было присвоено в области видимости создания экземпляра.

Comment: Уважаемые. я понял свою ошибку. Вопрос сотается тем же, а код поменяю.

Comment: @kovdryavlad, ну так тут и передай название: `MembershipFunctionParam a = new MembershipFunctionParam() { Name = "a" };`

Comment: А зачем вам это? Уж не хотите ли вы обращаться к свойствам по строковому имени, как в PHP?

Comment: @VladD, скорее для того, чтобы когда вызывался `ToString` были записи соответствующие именам

Comment: @VladD Мне нужно для того, чтобы выводить на форму Params c подписями. Я заметил, что все имена которые я создаю для полей совпадают с именами,которые я бы хотел выводить.

Comment: @kovdryavlad: Ага, понимаю. На мой вкус, лучше всё-таки «раздавать» имена вручную.

Answer (score 2):

Никакой магии не будет, чем ты не разметил класс, тебе всё равно нужна точка входа, в которой будет выполнено указание имени. Можешь сделать вот так, при помощи Reflection. Можешь заменить поля свойствами и делать это в сеттерах. Можешь перейти к [AOP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) или кодогенерации. Но в итоге всё равно будет код, который раздаёт имена и точка входа, в которой он дёргается.

```
static readonly FieldInfo[] membershipFunctionParamFields = typeof(TriangleFunction).GetFields(
          BindingFlags.Instance
          | BindingFlags.Public
          | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Where(f=> f.FieldType == typeof(MembershipFunctionParam)).ToArray();



public void RefreshNames()
{
    TriangleFunction instance = this;

    foreach (var field in membershipFunctionParamFields)
    {
        var value = (MembershipFunctionParam)field.GetValue(instance);
        if (ReferenceEquals(value, null))
            continue;

        value.Name = field.Name;
    }
}
```